# Login with LinkedIn is returning "The application is disabled"

Tags: authentication, frontend, linkedin-api

I'm trying to set un a Log in with LinkedIn button. I followed all the steps in this post:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/django-authentication-with-facebook-instagram-and-linkedin#step-4-%E2%80%94-linkedin-authentication

The only difference is that my Authorized redirect URLs for your app is this one:

http://localhost:8000/auth/complete/linkedin-oauth2/

I added the keys in my backend, and I also added the "Sign In with LinkedIn" option inside the "products" tab.

But I'm still getting this message when I try to Log In:

[image: Error showed by LinkedIn]

I don't know if this is helpful, but I'm getting this error in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

I have no idea what is going on here, I can't find someone with the same problem.

Do you have any clue what can I be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the URL of that error page? You need to ensure that the `client_id` and the `redirect_uri` exactly match the settings of the app as you see them in the LinkedIn developer portal

Comment: Hello @smargh, thank you so much for your answer.

I've already fixed the problem. It wasn't the `redirect_uri` nor the `client_id`.

It was an outdated Django dependency.

Thank you so much anyway.

Comment: Got the same problem. Could you be more specific? Which Django dependency is? What version has to be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course @Gene9y, I'm sorry I wasn't specific enough.

This is the dependency I updated:

social-auth-core from 3.2.0 to 4.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by an outdated Django dependency.

The dependency was `social-auth-core` and I updated it from version 3.2.0 to 4.0.3, that fixed the problem.